# Magento Admin Panel turns into Text File

Tags: magento2, admin, locale, interface

After I "accidently" changed the Interface Locale in my Magento Admin Panel > Account Setting, the page reloaded and became a text page.
[image]

When I tried to change the Interface Locale again, the Save Account Button doesn't work anymore.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to app/etc/di.xml and search for line 607, comment the line.

```
<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>
```